# Playing .m3u8 video using php curl

Tags: php, curl, m3u8, php-curl

I'm attempting to play a .m3u8 video using a php curl proxy. The following code seems to work, although it only returns the video #EXTM3U information but does not play the video.

Code:

```
<?php
//....proxy info
$auth = 'username:password'; 
$proxy_ip = '1.2.3.4.5'; 
$proxy_port = 8080; 
$path = $_GET['link'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $path);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy_port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_ip);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $auth);
curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
    echo $error_msg;
}
curl_close($ch);
if (isset($error_msg)) {
    echo $error_msg;
}
?>
```

Output:

```
#EXTM3U #EXT-X-VERSION:3 #EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=5640800,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=5640800,CODECS="avc1.4d4028,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1920x1080,FRAME-RATE=25.000 index4147.m3u8 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2421100,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=2421100,CODECS="avc1.4d401f,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1280x720,FRAME-RATE=25.000 index2073.m3u8 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1566400,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=1566400,CODECS="avc1.4d401f,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=960x540,FRAME-RATE=25.000 index1296.m3u8 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1002100,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=1002100,CODECS="avc1.77.30,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=746x420,FRAME-RATE=25.000 index783.m3u8 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=774400,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=774400,CODECS="avc1.77.30,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=640x360,FRAME-RATE=25.000 index576.m3u8 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=421300,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=421300,CODECS="avc1.42c015,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=426x240,FRAME-RATE=25.000 index255.m3u8 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=476300,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=476300,CODECS="avc1.42c01f,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=640x360,FRAME-RATE=25.000 index101.m3u8
```

Any ideas regarding how I can play the video?

Comment: Send the proper MIME type before curl outputs the response.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [php update m3u8 file before curl file](//stackoverflow.com/q/31309835)

Comment: I'm still unable to play the video with the MIME type set. Any other alternative?

Comment: No. Rather do some debugging with `wget -S -O- http://localhost/m3ustealscript.php` on how the repsonse differs from the original resource. (Also I'd really like to know where all these m3u questions come from lately.)

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue...
Had any luck figuring it out?
I was also facing the same issue, until just a few moments ago.

Was able to generate a m3u8 file in php and set the mime type correctly but videojs and vlc just wouldn't play it...
If I downloaded the output, it would be good for vlc or videojs.

Followed a tip from **Markus AO** on [How to create dynamic m3u8 using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71299929/how-to-create-dynamic-m3u8-using-php) and it worked.

Basically, it should be ignoring the mime type (although I haven't tried removing it) and just looks at the extension.

Just used the htaccess to make it so that when they call some m3u8's it actually calls my php file

Added this to my **.htaccess**:

**RewriteRule ^proxy([^.]+).m3u8$ proxy.php**

I'm actually sending the address as a GET parameter such as your $_GET['link']
The wildcard in front of proxy and before the .m3u8 extension is just because I've noticed that a plugin that I've installed in chrome would probably ignore that the parameter changed and just show the same stream as long as it was the proxy.m3u8 file.

Hoping this can be helpful to anybody