# Playing .m3u8 hls using php curl

Tags: php, curl, proxy, scripting, get

I'm attempting to play a .m3u8 video using a PHP curl proxy. The following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52203064/playing-m3u8-video-using-php-curl) doesn't work:

```
     <?php
    //http://127.0.0.1/m3u8.php
    //....proxy info
    $auth = 'username:password'; 
    $proxy_ip = '1.2.3.4.5'; 
    $proxy_port = 8080; 
    $path = $_GET['link'];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $path);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy_port);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_ip);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $auth);
    curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_error($ch)) {
        $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
        echo $error_msg;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    if (isset($error_msg)) {
        echo $error_msg;
    }
    ?>
```

Page returns "malformed malformed" error, any ideas to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What, the error message is supposed to be _just_ “malformed”? That is rather hard to believe. Can you wrap it in htmlspecialchars and see what you get then?

Comment: how do i use htmlspecialchars? can you give me an example please?

Comment: Seriously …? `echo htmlspecialchars ($error_msg);`

Comment: I did as you told me, but nothing changes, the page returns "<url> malformed<url> malformed", with the modification the <ul> tag was added

Comment: `<url>` or `<ul>`? Probably the former - then that would likely mean, the proxy server doesn’t like the URLs you are sending, and considers them malformed.

Comment: happens with all urls, i have reason to believe that it's a bug in the script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202269/discussion-between-fask-and-04fs).