# How to create dynamic m3u8 using php

Tags: php, m3u8

I'm having a problem with my code working. I'm trying to make it play videos in m3u8 format in jwplayer, using a php file, but I don't know where I'm going wrong.

I would like the video.php file containing the `file_get_contents('./video-001.m3u8')` of the m3u8 to work within the file field of the jwplayer, but as I mentioned the file does not work, because it is not being recognized by the jwplayer.

My code (video.php)

```
// Check if get id has been entered
$validarGet = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;
 
// Erases any kind of trace in the browser
$g = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s');
header('Expires: ' . $g . ' GMT');
header('Last-Modified: ' . $g . ' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
header('Pragma: no-cache');

// Check the domain reference
$parsed = empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? false : parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

if (false === empty($parsed['host']) && $parsed['host'] !== 'mysite.com') {
    header('Content-Type: application/x-mpegURL'); // Apply the mimetype needed for the player to recognize the file that is dynamically generated
    echo file_get_contents('./arquivo.m3u8'); // read your file
} else {
    echo 'You are not authorized to access this file';
}
```

Comment: Consider using a filename with an expected extension, e.g. `video.m3u8`, and use `mod_rewrite` to return your `video.php` script when it's accessed.

Comment: If I understand correctly you talk about taking the video.php file and renaming it to video.m3u8 then using htaccess , to make the file even with the php code work as .php again through the rewrite rules.

with something like this
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*\.(?:ts|m3u8)$ video.php [NC,L,QSA]

Comment: You don't have to make all `m3u8` files execute PHP. That'd be a potential mess. Your `video.m3u8` doesn't need to _actually_ exist, all you need is a rewrite rule pointing requests to it to your `video.php`. Something like `RewriteRule video\.m3u8 video.php` would do it for one file. Otherwise, `RewriteRule (.+)\.m3u8 test.php?video=$1` if you wanted to pass the "filename" to your script as a query string.